# Message routing and its speed

Tags: botframework

I am trying to route messages using Bot Framework (from one account to another). Unfortunately the time passed between the moment the message is sent and delivered is about 3 sec on real bot (~1.5 sec on emulator). Is there any ability to increase it? 1.5 sec can be acceptable, but 3 sec delay is really annoying.
Here is the code from the Post method and from the dialog.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody] Activity message)
    {
        if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            await Conversation.SendAsync(message, () => new SendingTestDialog());
        }
        return new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
    }

[Serializable]
public class SendingTestDialog : IDialog
{
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);

    }

    public async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
    {
        var messageReceived = await argument;
        var message = context.MakeMessage();
        message.Type = messageReceived.Type;
        message.From = new ChannelAccount("MyBotId", "MyBotName");
        message.ChannelId = "telegram"; //doesn't really matter
        message.Recipient = new ChannelAccount("RoutedToAccId", "RoutedAccName");
        message.Text = "**Test**: " + messageReceived.Text;            
        message.Conversation = new ConversationAccount(false, "RoutedToAccId", "RoutedAccName");            

        var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri("https://telegram.botframework.com/"));
        await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync((Activity)message);
        context.Done(new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved speed issues in Direct Line API by changing my Azure Deployment Location to West US.

Comment: Thank you (and @Jim Lewallen) very much for your answers. Changing server location helped to get about 1.5x speed boost!

Answer (score 1):

Can you confirm where your bot is deployed, and where you're located? (continent is all I need). I'm trying to figure out if there is cross-ocean latency involved.

Comment: My bot is deployed in West Europe on Standard: 1 Small Service plan. We are located in Saint Petersburg (Russia).

Comment: That may be a big part of it.  The bot framework servers are currently deployed in east and west US.  Upside to this is we have plane to expand datacenters to western Europe and Asia later this year.